# Why my tensor still have the rank 2 after a reshape to 3D

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is my script. `

```
def phi(x, b, w, B):
    z1 = tf.matmul(x,w)
    z2 = tf.cos(z1+b)
    w1 =tf.reshape(w,(1,2,1000))
    #z= tf.reshape(z2,(100,1,1000))
    z=tf.expand_dims(z2, 1)
    print(z)
    print(w1)
    phix = tf.matmul(z, tf.transpose(w1))
    phix /= tf.sqrt(float(float(int(w.get_shape()[2])) / 2.))
    #print(phix)
    phix = np.reshape(phix,(200,1000))

    return phix,B



def model(phix, B, param) :
    #return tf.matmul(tf.matmul(phix, tf.transpose(param)), B)
    one = tf.matmul(phix, param)
    return one
x2 = tf.constant(Xtr)  # variable
#xtest = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1925, 2])  # variable

#W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]),trainable=False ,name="W2")
W2 = tf.constant(np.random.normal( loc = .0 , scale = 1./20. ,size =[2, 1000] ),name="W2")
#b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]),trainable=False , name="b2" )
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[1000],dtype=tf.float64),trainable=False , name="b2")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [100, 2])
#ytest = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [1925, 2])
B = W2

param = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1000]))  # variable trainable
norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(param)) ## attention ici c'est par ce que param est un vecteur de une dimmention 
phix, B = phi (x2,b2,W2,B)
lamda = 1.e-43 
y_ = model(phix, B,param)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_)) 


step = 0.002


opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(step).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))       
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


d = {}
evolution_train = []
evolution_cost = []
iteration = range(10000)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for k in [10000] :
        for i in range(k):
            batch_ys = ytr
            #batch_xs = Xtr

            #X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(batch_xs, batch_ys, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
            p = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = { y : batch_ys })


            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={y: batch_ys})
            evolution_cost.append(p)
            evolution_train.append(train_accuracy)
            #print(p)
            if i%100 == 0:
                print("step " +str(i)+ " cost " +str(p)+ " train_accuracy " +str(train_accuracy)+ " --- %s seconds --- " % (time.time() - start_time))


        d["cost for " +str(k) + " iteration"] = p
```

`
I reshape well z but when I do  phix = tf.matmul(z, tf.transpose(w1)) the following message appears : ValueError: Shapes (100, 1, 1000) and (?, ?) must have the same rank

this is the error :

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    546       try:
--> 547         self.assert_same_rank(other)
    548         new_dims = []

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_same_rank(self, other)
    592         raise ValueError(
--> 593             "Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other))
    594 

ValueError: Shapes (100, 1, 1000) and (?, ?) must have the same rank

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in with_rank(self, rank)
    622     try:
--> 623       return self.merge_with(unknown_shape(ndims=rank))
    624     except ValueError:

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    553         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" %
--> 554                          (self, other))
    555 

ValueError: Shapes (100, 1, 1000) and (?, ?) are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-1f84fec5a618> in <module>()
     33 param = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1000]))  # variable trainable
     34 norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(param)) ## attention ici c'est par ce que param est un vecteur de une dimmention
---> 35 phix, B = phi (x2,b2,W2,B)
     36 lamda = 1.e-43
     37 y_ = model(phix, B,param)

<ipython-input-75-1f84fec5a618> in phi(x, b, w, B)
      7     print(z)
      8     print(w1)
----> 9     phix = tf.matmul(z, tf.transpose(w1))
     10     phix /= tf.sqrt(float(float(int(w.get_shape()[2])) / 2.))
     11     #print(phix)

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in matmul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, a_is_sparse, b_is_sparse, name)
   1034                                    transpose_a=transpose_a,
   1035                                    transpose_b=transpose_b,
-> 1036                                    name=name)
   1037 
   1038 sparse_matmul = gen_math_ops._sparse_mat_mul

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in _mat_mul(a, b, transpose_a, transpose_b, name)
    909   """
    910   return _op_def_lib.apply_op("MatMul", a=a, b=b, transpose_a=transpose_a,
--> 911                               transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
    912 
    913 

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    653         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    654                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 655                          op_def=op_def)
    656         outputs = op.outputs
    657         return _Restructure(ops.convert_n_to_tensor(outputs), output_structure)

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   2154                     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   2155     if compute_shapes:
-> 2156       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
   2157     self._add_op(ret)
   2158     self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   1610       raise RuntimeError("No shape function registered for standard op: %s"
   1611                          % op.type)
-> 1612   shapes = shape_func(op)
   1613   if len(op.outputs) != len(shapes):
   1614     raise RuntimeError(

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/common_shapes.py in matmul_shape(op)
     79 def matmul_shape(op):
     80   """Shape function for a MatMul op."""
---> 81   a_shape = op.inputs[0].get_shape().with_rank(2)
     82   transpose_a = op.get_attr("transpose_a")
     83   b_shape = op.inputs[1].get_shape().with_rank(2)

/Users/DEMANOU/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in with_rank(self, rank)
    623       return self.merge_with(unknown_shape(ndims=rank))
    624     except ValueError:
--> 625       raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
    626 
    627   def with_rank_at_least(self, rank):

ValueError: Shape (100, 1, 1000) must have rank 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You did `phix = np.reshape(phix,(200,1000))` using numpy to do the reshape. I think you meant to do `phix = tf.reshape(phix,(200,1000))` so tensorflow does it right?

Numpy doesn't get used at computation time, only tensorflow operations get used.

Comment: Yes it's the mistake, I meant to write phix = tf.reshape(phix,(200,1000)).

Comment: So you have two phases to look at, first you define your graph structure, then you're running the computations in the graph. To debug this it's common to add print statements when you define your graph structure. When you print a tensor you should see that the expected shape of the tensors is what you expect. I think you're getting confused by tensorflow needing to be set up first and then run. Another error I see is: `tf.sqrt(float(float(int(w.get_shape()[2])) / 2.))`, you're mixing TF operations with python operations. The python operations only run at graph setup, not at computation.

Comment: `w.get_shape` in this case is only run at graph setup time, but `tf.sqrt` is being run at computation time. It's pretty common to get these mixed up, I did it myself quite a bit in the beginning too. Hopefully I'm not too far off base, there's a lot there to digest, and I'm not following every bit of it.

Comment: What are the values of printing `z` and `w1` by the way?

Comment: thanks, I corrected my mistake in tf.sqrt but I get the same error. I already put print to debug. The values of z and w are respectively Tensor("ExpandDims_5:0", shape=(100, 1, 1000), dtype=float64) and 
Tensor("Reshape_62:0", shape=(1, 2, 1000), dtype=float64)

Comment: the problem comes from the function convert_to_tensor in the function matmul but I don't understand why it changes my shape for w and not for z.

Comment: The fact that you have 62 reshape ops, "Reshape_62:0" concerns me. It sounds like you are creating tf reshape ops in a loop, perhaps each training iteration? I don't see how you got that from your code, but it looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Yes now I use tf.expand_dims but I still get the same problem

Comment: I'm confused. So you said in comments that you have shapes `(100, 1, 1000)`, and `(1,2,1000)` for `z` and `w1`, you're transposing `w1` so unless I'm wrong that's turning into `(1,1000,2)`, then you're trying to multiply these numbers together. The first dimension should be representing the batch size, which should be equal I believe, so that seems like an issue. Also, you should probably break out all steps to individual lines and print out the results at each step to make sure things are happening the way you expect. I don't see how you got a 2 dimensional vector in there. Print statements.